# Scala - Pass in a void function as a parameter

Tags: scala

I have a class with a constructor as defined below:

```
class Worker(val action: String, val owner: Component,
         validate: (RequestScopeObject) => Boolean,
         model: (RequestScopeObject) => Unit,
         connector: (RequestScopeObject) => Unit)
```

and another java class called FrameFactory with a method as below:

```
public static <T extends Component> T 
   createContainerAndShow(String framesetid, Component component)
```

When I am creating an instance of the Worker class as below:

```
new Worker(
    action = "actionName",
    owner = null,
    validate = (scopeObject) => {true},
    model = (scopeObject) => {},
    connector = (scopeObject: RequestScopeObject) => {
      FrameFactory.createContainerAndShow("string", new JPanel())
      () // forced to put a '()'  here as FrameFactory.createContainerAndShow 
         //returns the Jpanel created
    }
  ))
```

I was wondering if there was any way of writing this better? How do i declare the connector parameter as a function that returns Unit and ignore the JPanel returned by FrameFactory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply ignore the fact that your connector looks like it is returning a frame, compiler knows that it is function `RequestScopeObject => Unit` and it will be treated as such. You can think of it like compiler will add `()` as last statement in your function.

Also note that you don't need curly braces if you have one instruction only, and you don't need parens around single argument as well.

```
new Worker(
  action = "actionName",
  owner = null,
  validate = scopeObject => true,
  model = scopeObject => (),
  connector = scopeObject =>
    FrameFactory.createContainerAndShow("string", new JPanel())
))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not forced to put `()` at the end of the function block. If your function return type is of type `Unit` the instance resulting of the last block expression won't be returned.

Consider the following example:

```
def f(g: Int => Unit) = {}
f((x: Int) => 3)
```